# Protect a buffer from accidental editing

Tags: text-editing, read-only

Sometimes I want to prevent myself from accidentally editing a buffer. How can I write-protect the buffer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can toggle `read-only-mode` on a buffer with `C-x C-q`: the mode line changes from `-:--- README.org ...` to `-:%%- README.org ...`  (where `README.org` is the name of the file that the buffer is visiting, although `read-only-mode` applies to any buffer, including buffers that are *not* associated with files). That indicates that the buffer is `read-only`: trying to modify the buffer afterwards (e.g. by typing `RET`) elicits the message `newline: Buffer is read-only: #<buffer README.org>`.

See the description of `read-only-mode` with `C-h f read-only-mode`. There are several wrinkles described there that I do not describe above. For a description of the mode line (including the `read-only` bits described above), see the [Mode line](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Mode-Line.html) section in the Emacs manual.

`read-only-mode` is a minor mode and like all minor modes, running the mode function (with `M-x read-only-mode` or more simply with the keybinding `C-x C-q`)  toggles the mode from `off` to `on` or vice versa. Underneath the covers, the mechanism uses the `buffer-read-only` buffer-local variable that @shynur describes in [his answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/78325/14825) but there is generally no need to muck around with that interactively. Changing `read-only` status from a program is a different matter: the doc string of the mode is a must-read in that case.

Answer (score 3):

Buffer local variable: `buffer-read-only`

---

Usages:

- Put it in your file:

  ```
  Your text...

  Local Variables:
  buffer-read-only: t
  End:
  ```

  Save your file and then `M-x normal-mode`.
- Set it manually, say `M-: (setq-local buffer-read-only t)`
  (`setq-local` is unnecessary, but it is more readable than `setq` when you set a buffer local variable).

Comment: Great idea. You could even define a keybinding for `(setq-local buffer-read-only t)`.

Comment: `C-x C-q` is bound to `read-only-mode`, a minor mode, so you can use it to toggle the read-only state of a buffer.

Comment: @NickD If you provide this as an answer, it would be very helpful. I could do it, but I don't want to lay claim to your idea.

Comment: henning: NickD already told you the standard key binding for the standard command to do that.  There's no reason to add custom code to this answer.

Comment: @phils the custom code doesn't trigger `read-only-mode`, though. The addition just complements the original approach suggested in this answer. As soon as @NickD converts their comment into an answer, I will accepted it as the default solution.

Comment: henning: Don't be so sure.  Your code wasn't triggering the *message*, but it's setting the same variable: `read-only-mode` specifically toggles `buffer-read-only` (old-timers know this command as `toggle-read-only`; it was reframed as `read-only-mode` a while ago, but there was never a `read-only-mode` variable).  Try alternating your command and read-only-mode and you'll see that they're both controlling the same thing.  Other than the toggling behaviour, the main difference relates to the `view-read-only` user option (but that's not enabled by default).

Answer (score 0):

Just toggle `view-mode`, which "[provides commands for scrolling through the buffer conveniently but not for changing it](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/View-Mode.html)". Typing `q` disables view-mode and returns to the previous buffer. Typing `e` disables view-mode and keeps the current buffer visible, e.g. for editing.

Comment: If it is possible for you to edit accidentally, the same is true for you to press `e` accidentally.

Comment: That is true, but less likely. Assuming (somewhat unrealistically) that all keys on a keyboard have the same probably of being hit accidentally, and assuming the number of keys is 100, it is even 100 times less likely. But I really welcome better suggestions.

Comment: "*better suggestion*" -- `buffer-read-only`

Comment: Write it up, and if it works, I'll gladly accept.